# Same title for every tex template

Tags: macros, chapters, titles, article

I have a TeX document that includes several TeX documents.

The question is that the contents of the attached documents are different and the number of pages may also differ, but I need the same text (title) on each page of the template. I left the example below, thank you all, I will be very happy and grateful for any help.

I draw your attention to the fact that the pages are stretched by the amount of content, I cannot explicitly indicate the page break.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
    \input{first_document.tex}
    \input{second_document.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you specify the title for each `\input`/file? Is there a `\title` command inside each?

Comment: Titles or page headers?  Seems that you need the `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: @Fran
Yes! You were right, I used the fancyhdr package and did what I needed, thanks for the help!